# Django - Issue during split views.py file

Tags: python, django, import

I'm developing a Django application (Django 1.10 + Python 2.7.9) and I would split my views.py file in a sub-directory. I searched a lot about this topic and I have found posts and SO questions, but when I try to replicate them, I faced this error:

> RuntimeError: Model class models.Evento doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Before split-attempt, the application worked well. 
Follow my project structure:

```
-gest_fest
    -gest_fest_app
        -gest_fest
            -views
                -__init__.py
                -eventi.py
            -models.py
            -urls.py
```

**views.__init__.py**

```
from eventi import eventi_view
```

**views.eventi.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import Evento


def eventi_view(request):
    events = Evento.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'eventi/eventi.html', {'eventi': events})
```

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Evento(models.Model):
    id_evento = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    titolo = models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from views.eventi import eventi_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^eventi/$', eventi_view, name='eventi')
]
```

Settings.py information

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
ROOT_URLCONF = 'gest_fest_app.urls'
STATIC_URL = '/gest_fest/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/gest_fest/static/")
]
```

I have found some solutions that suggest using relative imports, but I would utilize the absolute ones.

I have noticed, that this error raise in `from models import Evento` (views.eventi.py).

What i'm missing? 
If I missed some usuful information about the project, I will edit it.

Sorry for trivial question, but I'm a novel in Django.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code has implicit relative imports: a very nasty thing. I would strongly suggest adding `from __future__ import absolute_import` to the top of all Python 2 files which will prohibit them. Despite the name, you can then use either *explicit relative* imports or absolute imports. This is probably clouding your real issue, as in your case, I actually don't see how `from models import Evento` *works at all* in `views/eventi.py`.

Comment: @NickT, first of all thanks for the replay. I suspected that the problem is linked to imports. Can you please provide me a simple example with your solution please? I would like have a "clean-imports"

Comment: Just curious if `from ..models import Evento`  works?

Comment: @Giordano paste `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of *every* file and re-run. Fix the import errors, see if you get the same error after that.

Comment: @NickT, ok, i tried but same issue. any suggestions?

Comment: @zatta, yes it works. but why? how can i solve?

Comment: What command are you executing to get that error? Where are those files, where's your settings file?

Comment: I ran a simply runserver command, and about files, i have posted the project structure

Comment: Two dots work relatively, single dot means "current", two dots mean "up from current" and so on. For absolute imports have you tried `from gest_fest.models import Evento` ?